# How to assign IPv4 address to routers?

Tags: networking, ip, router, hosts

I can't seem to understand how to assign the IP address to routers.
Could someone explain how to get the IP address for the router? (image 1)

this is a diagram included in our course lecture
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD2kW.png)

I found similar questions but using programming languages it's not the way I am looking for so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Router on the image have three interfaces with IPs:

- 223.1.1.4
- 223.1.3.27
- 223.1.2.9

To change it, you need to change the IP of the interface using some programming language like CISCO iOS CLI.

If you want to add some device to a virtual network, be careful with the subnet mask.

In the example, the subnet mask of all interfaces is probably 255.255.255.0 with 223.1.1.0/24,223.1.2.0/24 and 223.1.3.0/24 prefixes. So, if you want to add a device to a VLAN, you need to use an IP with the same network prefix.

If you want to add a device in the 223.1.1.0/24 VLAN, you need to specify 223.1.1.X IP, with 255.255.255.0 subnet mask and 223.1.1.4 as default gateway.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear, I am not trying to change it but sometimes we get a question telling us to assign the ip addresses and they give us some of them to start with... knowing these how can I assign the routers their IP addresses?

Comment: could you help me please?

Comment: Edited answer. You should take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Comment: I didn’t know I should do that sorry